# Lazy for html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using lazy for my images [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) plugin I'm looking for a way to do html content but I couldn't do that for html is there any way to do simply ? and my html structure

```js
$('.lazy.teaser.lazy_content').on('lazyunveilread', function (ev) {

            data_url = $(this).attr("data-url");
            data_id = $(this).attr("data-target-id");

            $.ajax({
                url: data_url,
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $(".loaderDiv").show();
                    $("#" + data_id).html("");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".loaderDiv").hide();
                    $("#" + data_id).html(data);
                }

            })


        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/3.0.0/lazysizes.min.js"></script>

<div class="trustyou-detail-box section lazy teaser lazy_content" data-url="/ajax/yorumlar/@Model.OtelBilgileri.seflink" data-expand="-210" data-target-id="ajax-content" id="yorumlar-area">
  <h4 class="tur-main-baslik section-head">YORUMLAR</h4>
  <div id="ajax-content"></div>
</div>
```

I have `data-url` and `data-target-id` to get url and my content

Comment: can you reword or elaborate? I am not sure I can follow what you are trying to do here...

Comment: after scroll down I want to load my content page (lorem ipsum,p,div or another page) I mean I have ajax page and I want to show them after scroll down and  and I updated my code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
<!-- The ID (id="ajax-content) is redundant -->
<div class="lazyload" data-url="...">
    <div class="loaderDiv"></div>
</div>

$(document).on('lazybeforeunveil', function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    $target.load($target.data('url'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/80hg2ykv/4/

Comment: hi this is useful but not working on my project I have html element forms,table and something like that..does it only work with text ?

Comment: oo thanks but my data url something like that `data-url="/ajax/Prices/@Model.HotelsInformation.seflink"` but it doesn't work what kind of problem can be ? just guess

Comment: Open a link (`/ajax/Prices/@Model.HotelsInformation.seflink`) in browser and check the problem. Probably you need access it via POST or transfer some parameters. Without additional information impossible to detect a problem.

Comment: yes normally it work via POST my ajax post was like this https://pastebin.com/raw/e1zrCsMT

Comment: I mean my AJAX and jquery not enough to do something basic too..how can I apply this data-url with ajax post?

Comment: use short version https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ `$.post($target.data('url'), function(response) {    
     $target.html(response);
    });`

Comment: its' great and work very well thank you so another and last question is  how can I get my content inside  div for example I have `.myBox` div and I want to get my content inside this div

Comment: `$target.find('.myBox')` after `$target.html(response)`